# how divide NSMutableDictionary into two NSMutableArrays?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to divide a NSMutableDictionary into two NSMutableArrays on comparing one keyValue in NSMutableDictionary,

example:**My NSMutableDictionary**

```
    [
        {
            "0": "87",
            "1": "13270690451",
            "2": "Delhi night's",
            "3": "2106",
            "4": ":)",
            "5": "Kunwar",
            "6": "28.601736",
            "7": "77.159178",
            "8": "16.107459108715",
            "timeleft": "87",
            "imageurl": "13270690451",
            "beep": "Delhi night's",
            "beepid": "2106",
            "beepdescription": ":)",
            "username": "Kunwar",
            "Lat": "28.601736",
            "long": "77.159178",
            "distance": "16.107459108715"
        },
        {
            "0": "87",
            "1": "13278710651",
            "2": "Delhi IT hub",
            "3": "2145",
            "4": "LPT certification centre",
            "5": "Kunwar",
            "6": "28.491764",
            "7": "77.082712",
            "8": "2005.6281723630008",
            "timeleft": "87",
            "imageurl": "13278710651",
            "beep": "Delhi IT hub",
            "beepid": "2145",
            "beepdescription": "LPT certification centre",
            "username": "Kunwar",
            "Lat": "28.491764",
            "long": "77.082712",
            "distance": "2005.6281723630008"
       }
]
```

i want make two seperate mutablearray if "distance": "2005.6281723630008" in dictionary is less than 500 add to mutable array1 other wise add to mutable array2

Comment: That doesn't look like a Dictonary. That looks like an Array of Dictionaries.

Comment: Is there any way to sort this a according to my query??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [originalArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    float fa = [[(NSDictionary*)a objectForKey:@"distance"] floatValue];
    float fb = [[(NSDictionary*)b objectForKey:@"distance"] floatValue];
    NSNumber *first = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fa];
    NSNumber *second = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fb];

    return [first compare:second];
}];

NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *dic in sortedArray) {
    if ([[dic objectForKey:@"distance"] floatValue] < 500.0f) {
        [arr1 addObject:dic];
    } else {
        [arr2 addObject:dic];
    }
}
originalArray = nil;
```

Comment: @iphoneDev You really shouldn't use this, NSPredicate is much faster.

Comment: You could constrain a search with an `NSPredicate` approach. But I think the author would have enough trouble with something like above.

Answer (score 1):

[NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) was made for this task, you can use it like this:

```
#define DOUBLE_OBJ(x) [NSNumber numberWithDouble:x]
NSDictionary *location1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:DOUBLE_OBJ(16.107459108715) forKey:@"distance"];
NSDictionary *location2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:DOUBLE_OBJ(2005.6281723630008) forKey:@"distance"];
NSDictionary *location3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:DOUBLE_OBJ(250) forKey:@"distance"];
NSDictionary *location4 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:DOUBLE_OBJ(750) forKey:@"distance"];

NSMutableArray *locations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:location1, location2, location3, location4, nil];

NSArray *locationsLessThan500 =    [locations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"distance < 500"]];
NSArray *locationsGreaterThan500 = [locations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"distance > 500"]];

NSLog(@"locations: %@", locations);
NSLog(@"locations less than 500: %@", locationsLessThan500);
NSLog(@"locations greater than 500: %@", locationsGreaterThan500);
```

Of course, if distance is equal to 500, the result will not appear in either array.

Comment: the location u hardcode do it need to do it? as i already have a mutable array with key "distance"

Comment: i get this error using this -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11cda0

Comment: @iPhoneDev no, you don't need to hardcode the length. If you already have an array, then you can simply use the `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` call.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're parsing JSON. First, tell whoever produced that data that JSON supports numbers. Lat, long and distance should be numbers, not strings. And who uses one key with an uppercase L and one key with a lowercase l? Can't these people use their keyboards? That is *so* asking for trouble, where someone *will* use the wrong spelling and search for hours for the bug.

```
NSMutableArray* shortDistance = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* longDistance = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary* dict in myArray)
{
    if (dict [@"distance"].doubleValue < 500.0)
        [shortDistance addObject:dict];
    else
        [longDistance addObject:dict];
}
```

Never use floatValue, unless you have a good reason that you can explain and defend why you would use floatValue and not doubleValue.

If there is any possibility that your data has null values for the distance, you'll need to check for that or your program will crash.

Not enough points to add comments yet:

That DOUBLE_OBJ macro is just awful. To get an NSNumber with a value, write for example

```
@100 // Same as [NSNumber numberWithInt:100]
@12.34 // Same as [NSNumber numberWithDouble:12.34]
double x = ...; double y = ...; @(x + y) // Same as [NSNumber numberWithDouble:x + y]
```

It's part of the Objective-C language. And you write

```
NSDictionary *location1 = { @"distance": @16.107459108715 };
NSDictionary *location2 = { @"distance": @2005.6281723630008 };
NSDictionary *location3 = { @"distance": @250 };
NSDictionary *location4 = { @"distance": @750 }; 

NSArray *locations = @[location1, location2, location3, location4];
```